# Unable to Logout of WSFed App

Tags: single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, ws-federation, federation

I'm entirely new to WS Federation, and am tasked with insuring that Single Singout works. I have a function in a WS-Fed App (MVC):

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    string idpSingleLogoutUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettings.IdpSingleLogoutUrl];
    string spSingleLogoutUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettings.SpSingleLogoutUrl];
    WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(idpSingleLogoutUrl), new Uri(spSingleLogoutUrl));
    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut(false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The problem is, the Identity Provider I am working with is making calls to this method as redirects to...
https://testMachine04/Test/account/LogOff?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0

I can't debug the method because it doesn't run because of the query "wa=wsingoutcleanup1.0". I am still new to WS-FED and my management is expecting this soon. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The URL is actually case-sensitive. I changed it to (Lower-case Test) https://testMachine04/test/account/LogOff?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0, and it now logs off fine.